# How to have a validatation at the parent class, but not at the subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

Is it possible to do this? Example below:

```
class A
  validates_presence_of  :text

class B < A
  # should not validate text
```

Comment: you can add terrible if condition based on class name but it looks very weird

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class A
  # YES
  validates_presence_of :text, if: proc { |record| record.class === A }
  validates_presence_of :text, if: proc { |record| record.class == A }
  validates_presence_of :text, if: proc { |record| record.instance_of? A }

  # NO
  validates_presence_of :text, if: proc { |record| record.is_a? A }
  validates_presence_of :text, if: proc { |record| record.kind_of? A }
  validates_presence_of :text, if: proc { |record| record.class <= A }
  validates_presence_of :text, if: proc { |record| record.class < A }
end
```

I prefer `class ===` in such cases because I find it more explicit, but `instance_of?` is more readable... choose as you prefer.

Do not use `Object#is_a?`, `Object#kind_of?`, `Module#<=`, `Module#<` since the first three check for subclass or modules included, the fourth checks only for subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

My intuition tells me it likely isn't a good idea and you should probably examine why you are doing it this way, but...

You could do something like

```
validates_presence_of :text, :if => Proc.new{ |obj| obj instanceof A  }
```

Haven't tested that

Comment: Did you mean `obj.instance_of? A`?

Comment: Yep. I am too tired to be answering stuff online. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try sth like:

```
class B < A

  validators.find{|v| v.is_a? ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator}.attributes.delete :text
```

I hope there is a better way to do this though.